# Is there any way I can specify a custom region using Google Geochart?

Tags: google-visualization

I understand that I can get down to the metro level using the following in my options:

```
region: 'US-602',
resolution: 'metros',
```

But our client is asking for an even more specific map. First, they want it to be a square and every Geochart I've seen or tried in Google has been a fixed rectangle (fixed as in same proportion - I understand you can change the width and height). And I don't want to turn off 'keepAspectRatio' to make it a square since that will only stretch the map.

Is there any way I can specify specific coordinates (or do anything else) in Geochart to create my own custom region? I would think Google would allow you to customize something like region instead of pick from a list of fixed options.

Or is there any other plugin that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 4):

you can create custom maps for the GeoChart, however it gets a tad tricky. GeoChart expects your maps to be named in a certain way and be in a certain format, so you would have to reverse engineer how the maps are structured in order to draw your own. You can set to your own maps source by writing 
`google.visualization.GeoChart.setMapsSource(newSourceUrl).`

[read more](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/KVGu--jjUpk/L3yTtnmFU4kJ)